# Logarithm of imaginary numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

How do I solve this question?

[image: Question]

I tried using the quadratic formula on the question equation and got

$x_1 = 0.25 +1.089724..i = \ln r$

$x_2 = 0.25 -1.089724..i = \ln s$

I know $\ln x = \log_ex$, but how do I complete the questions with the imaginary numbers?

Comment: It should be $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you would apply euler's formula in this case? I'm having trouble applying it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the key of solving this question is to make use of the **RELATION OF ROOTS**.

**Recall:**

If $\forall a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$, given quadratic of $x$, $ax^2+bx+c=0$,

which can be converted to the form of $x^2+\frac bax+\frac ca=0$,

we say that $-\frac ba$ is the **sum of roots** and $\frac ca$ is the **product of roots**.

---

In this case, $\ln r$ and $\ln s$ are roots, so you can make use of these relations.

Comment: I agree that this is the intent of the book-writer, but the question as written is broken. For example, the notation $\log_r(s)$ doesn't make sense when $r$ and $s$ are complex numbers.

Comment: How do I solve the last question (d) using this relation?

Comment: As @hunter stated, the question involving the logarithm of complex number with complex base may be problematic. But if it is the way to do, convert $\log_r s$ to $\frac{\ln s}{\ln r}$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

For the $a)$ part, use Vieta's Formula: Sum  of roots of a quadratic equation is $\frac{-b}a$. 
So answer would be: $\frac12$. 
For $b)$ $\frac54$, using Vieta's Formulas for product of roots: $\frac ca$. 
For $c)$ the expression becomes $$\frac{\ln r+\ln s}{\ln r\ln s}=\frac{\frac12}{\frac54}=\frac25$$
For $d)$ use the properties of logarithms that $\log_rs=\frac{\log s}{\log r}$ and $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$. 

 So the given expression becomes $$\frac{(\log r+\log s)^2-2\log r\log s}{\log r.\log s}=\frac{\frac14-\frac{10}4}{\frac54}=\frac{-9}{5}$$